# How can I store two different render layers on separate render textures?

Tags: unity, scripting, layers

I'm using Camera.cullingMask to only render objects that belong to specific layers. However, I can't figure out how to render two different layers on the same frame and store them in separate render textures.

I tried rendering the other layer manually by creating a second camera, setting its position and rotation to the main camera, then rendering the output with Camera2.Render(), and storing it on a render texture with Grphics.Blit(). But the src render texture of OnRenderImage() didn't change to the layer rendered by the second camera after Camera2.Render() was executed.

Comment: Which render pipeline are you using? Have you tried assigning your render textures to the "target texture" fields of your cameras, so you don't have to manually blit into them, and using the cameras' depth to control rendering order rather than calling Render() manually?

Comment: I'm not using the node graph. I don't know if that makes a difference in the type of render pipeline. Are Camera.targetTexture() and Camera.SetTargetBuffers() same? If so, would keeping the second camera enabled and setting Cam2.targetTexture(example rendertexture) only render to that render texture instead of the active render texture?

Comment: The render pipelines are "Built In" and "Scriptable", the latter including "Universal (URP)" and "High Definition (HDRP)". [Setting `targetTexture` renders to that texture's colour and depth buffers instead of the screen / active render target](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-targetTexture.html). `SetTargetBuffers()` is more general and lets you specify one or more target colour and depth buffers separately. "Would X have Y result" is best answered by trying it — then you don't have to take my fallible word for it. 